# How to add a border to an image when a certain event happens WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, click, border

I have an Image in my WPF Window , and I need When a certain event happens ( button click ) the image is bordered through the C# code .. How can I do that ?
My image X: Name is " SwordIv " 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image in a border control, name it and change the BorderThickness from 0 to 1 if the button is clicked.